# Connecting mobile apps to a web service; What is it called and where do I start?

Tags: database, terminology, iphone, ios, web-services

I have some basic knowledge of iOS development and I want to now start connecting my apps to databases hosted on the internet, so that users will have access to remote / public data that pertains to my app.

My problem is that after searching the internet for some advice, I realised I don't even know what this type of programming is called? From my perusing it doesn't even appear to have a common moniker, and this is making it really difficult for me to find any advice on how to even begin learning to connect my apps to a web database.

So my questions are, what on earth is this discipline called? And, how can I get started in learning it?

Comment: popular naming for stuff like that seems to be **[wireless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wireless "see SO questions in this tag")** technologies, **[over-the-air](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/over-the-air "see SO questions in this tag")** (**[OTA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ota "see SO questions in this tag")**) access

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several options.

A current popular one is your server having a REST API that gives back JSON data.

Then in your app, you can make URL requests that will give back the JSON data (XML is another option). Parse the data and use as needed.

It is not nearly as simple as it sounds to set up the first time, but the key points are:
1) You will need to create a REST API
2) You will need to parse the data in the iphone app

Comment: I'd vote you up, but I can't, thanks for the advice :)

Comment: no problem, Welcome to programmers

Comment: resurrecting this thread because I would like to research the _design_ of this sort of setup on the client side - my main question is, from within the iOS app, what are some strategies for modularity/separation of responsibility? I just need a place to start my research. Much like the OP of this question, I don't know enough terminology to even begin searching for this information.

Answer (score 3):

Today the most common web services types are [SOAP and REST](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-calling-web-services/). There are some iOS application that use .Net Web Services and you can create your own as per your requirement. You can use either Json or xml for getting data from database through webservice.

**RestKit** is a generalized framework for consuming `JSON/XML` over `HTTP`. It will interoperate with any backend, providing the payload can be expressed as key-value coding key paths.

[Developing RESTful iOS Apps with RestKit](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/restkit_ios-sdk/)
Database seeding. When the Core Data object store is used, you can seed a database from a collection of data files.

Ref:
[REST Web Service for ResKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136971/rest-web-service-for-reskit)
[Rest API Web Service - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122574/rest-api-web-service-ios)

[Backing Your iOS App With WCF JSON Web Services](http://www.kotancode.com/2011/04/26/backing-your-ios-app-with-wcf-json-web-services/)

Comment: Great info, gives me much more to read/learn about :) Thanks!

Comment: @jarrod I upvoted Niranjan for you.  I know you cannot upvote, but I believe you can accept answers at this rep when you are ready.

Answer (score 0):

I use SudzC webservice generator every time, it will generate a complete set of required files
and it takes you less then 5 min to get started. Dont forget to watch the video tutorial, it will explain all you need to do.

http://sudzc.com/

Hope this help !!